# Sorting columns left to right in Google Sheets ascending order with app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to sort columns from left to right based on dates, here is an example of the issue that I'm facing:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CuDW-VRZxrwXXjyBj4BeUleMFqL8DUQrW3sku6WjMh0/edit?usp=sharing

I'm sorting from column E to N based on the dates in row 6. The script that I'm currently using works okay as far as cell E6 has a date and there is no empty columns in between the full ones, otherwise the script won't work.

Here's the script that I'm using:

```
function sortLToR() {
  
  //Defining the spreadsheet variables and setting ranges
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sort");
  var range3 = sheet.getRange(5, 5, 88,sheet.getLastColumn()-4)
  var range = sheet.getRange(5, 5, 88,sheet.getLastColumn()-4).getValues();
  Logger.log(sheet.getLastColumn())
  //Defining a blank array that can hold the result
  var trans = [];
  //transpose the data stored in range variable
  for(var column = 0; column < range[0].length; column++){
    trans[column] = [];
    for(var row = 0; row < range.length; row++){
      trans[column][row] = range[row][column];
    }
  }
    function sortByDate(a, b) {
    return new Date(b[1]).getTime() - new Date(a[1]).getTime();
}

var range2 = trans.sort(sortByDate);
var trans2 = [];
  //transpose the data stored in range variable
  for(var column = 0; column < range2[0].length; column++){
    trans2[column] = [];
    for(var row = 0; row < range2.length; row++){
      trans2[column][row] = range2[row][column];
    }
  }
  range3.setValues(trans2); 
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Sort Columns by date and move blank columns to right so that data always starts in Column E

This version puts the blank columns to the right and always starts at E

```
function sortLToR() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rg = sh.getRange(5, 5, sh.getLastRow() -4, sh.getLastColumn() - 4)
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  let b = transpose(vs);
  b.sort((a,b) => {
    if(a[1] && b[1]) {
      return new Date(a[1]).valueOf() - new Date(b[1]).valueOf();
    } else if(a[1] && !b[1]){
      return -1;
    } else if(!a[1] && b[1]) {
      return +1
    }
    
  });
  let c = transpose(b)
  rg.setValues(c);
}
```

Demo:

Before Sort:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 5/19/2022 | 5/18/2022 | 5/17/2022 | 5/16/2022 | 5/15/2022 | 5/14/2022 | 5/13/2022 | 5/12/2022 | 5/11/2022 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 |
|  |  |  |  |  | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 |

After Sort:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | COL10 | COL9 | COL8 | COL7 | COL6 | COL5 | COL4 | COL3 | COL2 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 5/11/2022 | 5/12/2022 | 5/13/2022 | 5/14/2022 | 5/15/2022 | 5/16/2022 | 5/17/2022 | 5/18/2022 | 5/19/2022 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 11 | 10 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 12 | 11 | 10 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 6 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 | 9 | 8 | 7 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 16 | 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 | 9 | 8 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 17 | 16 | 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 | 9 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 18 | 17 | 16 | 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 19 | 18 | 17 | 16 | 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 20 | 19 | 18 | 17 | 16 | 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 21 | 20 | 19 | 18 | 17 | 16 | 15 | 14 | 13 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 22 | 21 | 20 | 19 | 18 | 17 | 16 | 15 | 14 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 23 | 22 | 21 | 20 | 19 | 18 | 17 | 16 | 15 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 24 | 23 | 22 | 21 | 20 | 19 | 18 | 17 | 16 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 25 | 24 | 23 | 22 | 21 | 20 | 19 | 18 | 17 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 26 | 25 | 24 | 23 | 22 | 21 | 20 | 19 | 18 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 27 | 26 | 25 | 24 | 23 | 22 | 21 | 20 | 19 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 28 | 27 | 26 | 25 | 24 | 23 | 22 | 21 | 20 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 29 | 28 | 27 | 26 | 25 | 24 | 23 | 22 | 21 |  |  |

Comment: That worked great thx, but instead of setting the sorted values in columns E-H it set the values to columns F-I and left column E empty, I suppose because cell E6 has no date inside, is there's a way to set the values correctly in E-H columns? Thx again

Comment: I tested it.  It takes the data from E to the last column.  It transposes it and sorts the columns based upon data  in row 6 and then it transposes again and reposts it in the same colums from E to the last co.umn

Comment: It does but try it with column E totally empty, it won't set the results to E, it will keep E empty

Comment: No now it moves the empty columns to the right and it still starts in column E

Comment: I just modified the sort so that this always puts the blanck columns to the right and starts at column E

Comment: I tried several combinations of missing columns and this version now always moves the blank columns to the right and starts you data in column E

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a viable solution, but you could just add another sheet or use a range in columns to the right, I think you could accomplish what you want.

```
=transpose(sort(TRANSPOSE(filter(F:N,F:F<>"")),6,true))
```

See [example here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IZ7Log4maYH_fjZKZf7bBdhzxImMtlnUSa72czVSUG8/edit) of before and after.

Updated to account for potential breaks in data:

```
=transpose(sort(TRANSPOSE(filter(Before!E:N,Row(Before!E:E)<=max(arrayformula(--NOt(ISBLANK(Before!E:N))*row(Before!E:N))))),6,true))
```

One could then leverage this formula in an appscript to overwrite the data with something like this:

```
function makeRange(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const yourSheetName = "Before"; //sheet name with data
  const zFormula = "=transpose(sort(TRANSPOSE(filter('zzzzz'!E:N,Row('zzzzz'!E:E)<=max(arrayformula(--NOt(ISBLANK('zzzzz'!E:N))*row('zzzzz'!E:N))))),6,true))";//

  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet();
  var newFormula = zFormula.replace(/zzzzz/g,yourSheetName)
  newSheet.getRange("E1").setFormula(newFormula);

  var newValues = newSheet.getRange("E:N").getValues();
  
  ss.getSheetByName(yourSheetName).getRange("E:N").setValues(newValues);

  ss.deleteSheet(newSheet);
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution before but it didn't achieve what I'm trying to do, for example if column f is empty it will get an error

Comment: I tried your example and no error, it just pushed it to back of sorting.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, if column e were empty, or missing values, you'd be in trouble. Is there one column that would always have the maximum row? Alternatively,k is it always `F:N`?

Comment: So if you look at my example, I built columns showing the max rows in cells P1:Y1 and then a max total in z1, that can drive your filter and should get around any breaks in data.

Comment: Still doesn't work, also I don't want the results in a new sheet and this is why I was using a script to keep the data on the same sheet but sort them

Comment: @Frontlinemedical gotcha. I'll include a method which essentially does that, but not efficiently. If that doesn't work, no worries, it was fun messing around with.